# Compact space with a discrete subspace

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking for an example (or a proof of nonexistence) of a compact space with discrete and uncountable  subspace.Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other examples include $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ in the order topology induced by the lexicographic order: $(x,y) < (u,v)$ iff $x < u$ or ($x = u$ and $y < v$). This is compact as $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is order-complete. The subset $[0,1] \times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ is uncountable and discrete.

Or take $\{0,1\}^I$ for any (uncountable) index set $I$. This is compact by Tychonoff's theorem, and the set $A = \left\{(x_i) \in \{0,1\}^I: \left|\{i: x_i = 1\}\right| = 1\right\}$, all points that have exactly one $1$ (and the rest $0$) is discrete and of size $|I|$ (and adding the all $0$-point makes it homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of a discrete space of size $|I|$, BTW).

Answer (score 1):

Take the one-point (or any other) compactification of an uncountable discrete space. The space is open in its compactification and of course, remains discrete.

Another example is $[0,\omega_1]$ with the order topology. The set of successor ordinals is uncountable and discrete.